# How can I as beginner learn Sound Design cheap?

Tags: audio-recording, sound, design, film-mixing, cinema

I want to make a short animation video with some terrific 7.1 audio. Let that be my goal. Now where can I even begin to learn how to create small to big cinematic sounds, record good dialogue and how to mix everything so you feel as you're transported? I don't have 60k to pay for the university, so what can I do to to learn Sound Design for cheap?

Comment: Youtube, free. Search a little.

Comment: What about paid courses?

Comment: Of course it is always an alternative to pay for a courses. But which of them are worth it for you? I have no idea. Regardless, I and most of us and probably you, only learn from mistakes. So make many and learn a lot.

Comment: There are no short cuts - to be good at anything you learn it, you practice it, and you move from being terrible at it to perfecting it. That takes time, money or both.

Answer (score 4):

The best advice I can give is to make a lot of mistakes. And learn from them.

So, if you really are serious about this:

- start today. Select one animation, any animation already there, download it to your computer. Import it into a video editor -- I personally like Davinci Resolve as it is extremely complicated and very free. (Sorry should say extremely competent and free of cost).
- record sound using any microphone you have, maybe in your computer or your phone or anything really.
- combine the sound and video and admire the disaster. First mistake done, only about a few thousand left to do.

So, once you have done your first disaster, take millimeter steps forward towards getting better. The point is not to take mile long leaps, but to take small, small, miniature, baby steps. Every day. Make one new full recording + editing every day. Every day. In a year you have made about 365, most of them total disasters, and has learned a lot. You will probably have upgraded your software and hardware a bit -- but remember it is not the equipment that does it. Never believe the equipment makes the difference. **Never believe that equipment makes it.** When upgrading equipment go dirt cheap and when possible used and learn exactly what really makes a difference.

So after about one hundred mistakes and a thousand Youtube videos on how to make sound for video, you may now be ready to take the next step. The big point is that you now have invested not a lot of money but a lot of time, and now know more than anyone else in the whole world where you want to go next.